# Area 51 proposals have a "retag" button that doesn't do anything

Tags: bug, status-completed, area-51

There is a retag button on Area 51 proposals (perhaps available only if you have enough rep). This button doesn't do anything (there are no tags!), and results in a 404.

Comment: I thought I saw a proposal a couple of days ago that had been retagged (only visible in the edit history).

Comment: possible duplicate of ["retag" link visible when over 500 rep, but edit page not accessible](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/52038/retag-link-visible-when-over-500-rep-but-edit-page-not-accessible)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, we shouldn't have left that link in. It's been removed. Thanks.